# How can I add 'if condition' in primefaces, jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I wanna add this action. 
If EL is 'true' like this, #{trueFalseBean.isTrue}, I wanna pop up message without pressing any button like 'onload();', otherwise no action. How can I use if, else clause on JSF or PF? Please help me thanks

Comment: You don't need an `else` clause if there is nothing in it, and there is no `else` in XML. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I wanna add popup action when the value is true only, that should be 'onload();' action.

Comment: No `else` required by that. Question remains unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I just emphasize how to use IF CONDITION in this case (primefaces, jsf), you are right, no need to mention else condition.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, sometimes make sentences ambiguous, sorry for that.

Comment: So remove all mention of `else` from your question. And title.

Answer (score 0):

Define a boolean variable in your bean and set it with a method when an action is started. Then use variable last situation to make something.